# How to fix the scroll of the off-canvas menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an off-canvas menu. You can see that when the menu is open you can scroll the whole page as normal. **But what I want is when the menu is open you can't scroll any other part of the page but only the menu.** How can I do that please?

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/d8vuegq1/5/)

```
<div class="soround">
    <div class="m-nav-container">
        <nav>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            ...
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
    <button class="m-nav-opener">MENU</button>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set all the containers to `height:100%`, and set `overflow:hidden` to the `<body>` tag when the menu is open, so that to disable the scroll on the content area.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6ogssa1w/)**

```js
$(function () {
    $(".m-nav-opener").click(function () {
        if ($("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")) {
            $("body").removeClass("m-nav-open");
        } else {
            $("body").addClass("m-nav-open");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body, .soround {
    height: 100%;
}
.m-nav-container {
    background: silver;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    left: -300px;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.m-nav-open {
    transform: translateX(300px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="soround">
    <div class="m-nav-container">
        <nav>
            <p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p><p>menu</p>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
        <button class="m-nav-opener">MENU</button>
        <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```